# Inheritance windows forms with interfaces in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have a base windows forms class which contains two buttons: Ok and Cancel. This base form implements the interface `IBaseForm`:

```
public interface IBaseForm
{
  string FormText {get;set;}
  DialogResult ShowView(IWin32Window owner);
}

public partial class BaseForm : IBaseForm
{
  ...
}
```

Next I have a window class which inherits from `BaseForm` and implements another interface `IItem`:

```
public interface IItem : IBaseForm // here is problem
{
  string ItemName {get; set;}
  ...
}

public partial class AddItemForm : BaseForm, IItem
{
  ...
  // I don't have to implement IItem here, because it is implement in BaseForm
}
```

The problem is with the inheritance of `IBaseForm`; I have to inherit it two times.
In code I have:

```
IItem view = new AddItemForm();
view.FormText = "Add new item";
```

If I remove inheritance from `IItem`, `view.FormText` will be not visible. If I remove the inheritance from `BaseForm` I have to implement `IBaseForm` in each `AddItemForm`. I've only showed one itemForm but it is a lot, and I have to implement this many times.

How I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't another way to do this. BaseForm is a class, whereas IItem is an unrelated interface. Neither is a 'super' or 'base' of the other, so you need to inherit from IBaseForm in both of them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the problem; the code you've written compiles and runs just fine as you've written it.

`AddItemForm` inherits `BaseForm`'s implementation of `IBaseForm`, so doesn't have to re-implement `IBaseForm`.

Comment: I know that above code compiles successfull, but interface IBaseForm must be inherited two times.

Comment: `AddItemForm` has the `IBaseForm` interface applied to it twice - by inheriting from `BaseForm` and from implementing `IItem`, but that doesn't actually matter. It inherits its implementation from `BaseForm`, and therefore only *implements* it once.